# What kind of steak is this?

Tags: beef, steak, food-identification, cut-of-meat

I'm trying to identify what this steak is typically called, so I can know whether I am trimming and preparing it properly. I've been unable to find any photos of similar cuts.

I recently purchased a side of beef and we have some packs labelled "rib steak". These steaks look like this:

[image]

The steak is wedge-shaped. As I've indicated, a curved rib bone runs along one edge of the steak, and a strip of thick tissue runs along the other edge. About half of the cut (the narrower half) is mostly fat. When I trim this steak, I end up with the portion which I've colored red in my drawing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What part of the world are you in?  Meat cutting practices vary.  And do you have an actual photo?  The false perspective drawing is very confusing.

Comment: I'm in the southeastern USA. I'll try to add an actual photo later today.

Comment: Can't you ask who you got the side of beef from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you have what's commonly known as a rib eye. It comes from the same primal as the prime rib roast (or standing rib roast). Rib eye steaks are also known as rib steaks, delmonicos, scotch filets, etc. They can be found bone in or boneless and with the fat caps trimmed or not. It sounds to me like you have a bone in rib eye that hasn't had the fat trimmed.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if it was a ribeye because it doesn't look nearly as round or as wide as the ribeye photos I have seen.

Comment: Yes, the meaty portion of a rib eye tends to be much more compact, roundish, not oblong.

Comment: It is common for "rib eye" steaks to be boneless and thus the flat, fat cap and rib have been trimmed away. This usually leaves you with a roundish steak. With the bone in and all the fat, they usually look more wedge or chop shape.

Comment: Bone-in rib eyes are also called Cowboy Steaks in some parts of the US.